# Bayesian model for the reliability of a manufacturing process with noninformative prior

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, reliability

We have a manufacturing process $M$ with an **unknown** reliability $R \in (0,1)$, and, at the end of it, an automatic tool that sorts the good and bad products with a known efficiency of $E \in (0,1)$. Here is what I intend by 'reliability':

- Let us denote by  $X$  the random variable fabricated by a manufacturing process that represents the quality of a product and that can take on values in the set  $\{ 'good','bad'\}$.  Then, if  the latter process has a reliability of  $R$, we have  $\mathbb{P}(X = 'good') = R$.

We can show that the final reliability $R_f$ of $M$ is given by:

$$
R_f = \frac{R}{R + (1-E)(1-R)}       \ \ \ \ \ (1).
$$

This is equivalent to
$$
\mathbb{P}(X = 'good'|R) = R_f = \frac{R}{R + (1-E)(1-R)}
$$

The question is how to estimate $R_f$ since $R$ is unknown?

My first step was to suppose that $R \geq 0.5$ since it is a necessary condition for $R_f \geq E$ and that we can strongly hope that $M$ performs better than $0.5$.

My second step was to set a uniform prior $p_R$ for $R$ on the interval $(0.5,1)$. Then, this leads to:

$$
P(X = 'good') = \int_{0.5}^1 \mathbb{P}(X = 'good'|R) p_R(r) dr 
$$

$$
= \int_{0.5}^1 \frac{r}{r + (1-E)(1-r)} \cdot 2 dr
$$

$$
= \frac{2}{E} [r - K\ln(K+r)]\big|_{0.5}^1 
$$

$$
= \frac{2}{E} \cdot \left(0.5 + K\ln\left( \frac{K + 0.5}{K + 1} \right) \right) \ \ \ (2)
$$
where $K = \frac{1-E}{E}$.

Can one of you challenge a bit this result? is it a good idea to use the uniform prior as a non informative prior or other priors can be more appropriate?

Furthermore, something seems strange. Why, when $E$ goes to zero the expression (2) goes to infinity? This should be never larger than one.

Comment: As $E\to0$, expression (2) goes to $3/4$ in the limit.

Comment: Thanks jblood! Can you give me a hint please? Furthermore it makes sense since 3/4 is in the middle of the interval $(0.5,1)$ and, when $E=0$, the integral is simply the integral of the uniform $(0.5,1)$ distribution density on $(0.5,1)$.

Comment: I simplified to $$\frac{E+2(1-E)\ln{(1-E/2)}}{E^2}$$ Then L'Hôpital.

Comment: oh ok thanks very much :)

Comment: Is $E$ known, or is it also to be inferred from data?

Comment: it is known, I will precise it in the text!

Comment: How is $R\geq{0.5}$ a necessary condition for $R_f\geq R$? If $E=0$, $R_f$ always equals $R$.

Comment: My mistake, I modified it.